# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'clientId' does not exist in type 'RatesWhereUniqueInput'

Tags: typescript, apollo, prisma, typegraphql

I'm using typescript with prisma and typegraphql and getting this type error. RatesWhereUniqeInput is generated by prisma and is defining itself as a "CompoundUniqueInput" because the database I am referencing has 2 keys (clientId: string, employeeId: number).

In my repository I want to use both of these to reference a specific database line using "update()" but because the type is generated within the prisma client as clientId_employeeId? I am getting a type error.

repository function

```
    async update(model: Rates): Promise<Rates> {
        const { employeeId, clientId, ...data } = this.mapper.from(model);

        const entity = await this.db.rates.update({
            where: { employeeId, clientId },
            data: {
                ...data,
            },
        });

        return this.mapper.to(entity);
    }
```

prisma index.d.ts

```
  export type RatesWhereUniqueInput = {
    clientId_employeeId?: RatesClientIdEmployeeIdCompoundUniqueInput
  }
```

ratesmapper.ts

```
@injectable()
export class RatesMapper {
    public from(model: Rates): RatesEntity {
        return {
            employeeId: model.employeeId,
            clientId: model.clientId,
            rateFull: model.rateFull,
            rateQuarter: model.rateQuarter,
            rateLine: model.rateLine,
            rateWord: model.rateWord,
            createdAt: model.createdAt,
            updatedAt: model.updatedAt,
        };
    }

    public to(entity: RatesEntity): Rates {
        return new Rates({
            ...entity,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're trying to run a `update` query using prisma on single record from the `Rates` table/model. To do this you're getting an error in your `where` condition.

#### Solution

Try changing the `update` query as follows:

```js
const entity = await this.db.rates.update({
        where: {
            clientId_employeeId: {
                employeeId,
                clientId,
            },
        },
        data: {
            ...data,
        },
    });
```

This is the syntax Prisma uses when specifying the where condition for models with Compound ID or unique identifier (an ID or unique identifier that is made up of multiple fields of the model). You can read more in the **get record by compound ID or compound unique identifier** subsection of the [CRUD Reference Guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#get-record-by-compound-id-or-compound-unique-identifier) in the Prisma docs.

Comment: You just made my day! I read over half of those docs since yesterday and must have missed that part.